# Regex capture word within string oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have below sample of texts

```
b84fc77c7a0ec31a570e      "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="","CUST_INFO_TA"="wez","GROP"="D150" 
b84fc77c7eweweeee334      "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="","CUST_INFO_TA"="boz","GROP"="D150" 
b84fc77c7a0ec31a5     "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="yes","CUST_INFO_TA"="laz","GROP"="D250"
```

I want to capture the value within `"CUST_INFO_TA"="wez"` that is `wez`

i want my output to be

```
wez
boz
laz
```

i have managed to substr till `"CUST_INFO_TA"="wez"` and i am stuck to get to `wez`

```
select REGEXP_substr('b84fc77c7a0ec31a570e    "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="","CUST_INFO_TA"="wez","GROP"="D150"', 
'("CUST_INFO_TA"=.*?(\,|$))' ) FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about somewhat simpler

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'b84fc77c7a0ec31a570e      "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="","CUST_INFO_TA"="wez","GROP"="D150"' from dual union all
  3     select 'b84fc77c7eweweeee334      "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="","CUST_INFO_TA"="boz","GROP"="D150"' from dual union all
  4     select 'b84fc77c7a0ec31a5     "CUST_INFO_ACTIVE"="yes","CUST_INFO_TA"="laz","GROP"="D250"'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select regexp_substr(col, '\w+', instr(col, 'CUST_INFO_TA'), 2) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wez
boz
laz
```